# NoClassDefFoundError: android.security.MessageDigest

Tags: android

I've got an app where I'm seeing the following stack trace in the play developer console:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.security.MessageDigest
  at com.google.android.maps.KeyHelper.getSignatureFingerprint(KeyHelper.java:60)   
  at com.google.android.maps.MapActivity.createMap(MapActivity.java:513)
  at com.google.android.maps.MapActivity.onCreate(MapActivity.java:409)
  ...
```

the play console lists all these devices as type "OTHER". This is only happening to something like 1% of my users. What could be causing this? What could I do to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: are you using directly android.security.MessageDigest? can you use [java.security.MessageDigest](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/MessageDigest.html)?

Comment: this seems to be coming from Google maps API, have you tried to use a newer version of the API?  Other than updating maps API, there's not much you can do.

Answer (score 0):

`android.security.MessageDigest` was removed in Honeycomb, though there's no official record of this on android.com AFAIK

Try using `java.security.MessageDigest` in your import instead. Its been around since API 1 as well, so it will work on older devices, as well as Honeycomb and above. Just change the line:

```
import android.security.MessageDigest;
```

To

```
import java.security.MessageDigest;
```

Comment: This is coming from within google's MapActivity, I don't think I can change this.

Comment: @user291701 Those devices then probably have an older version of the Maps SDK, and were not updated by Google Play for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

The MessageDigest class is a helper class used to encode/decode keys, using common methods such as MD5 or SHA-1.

It seems that the class android.security.MessageDigest was removed from Honeycomb and later releases of Android, and must be replaced by java.security.MessageDigest (see this page)

Try downloading the latest version of the Google Maps API and rebuild your application with targetSDK set to the highest available (it should be 16 / Jelly Bean).

or

I have found simple work around! Just create in src directory package android\security and place MessageDigest.java inside.

```
package android.security;

import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

public class MessageDigest
{
    private java.security.MessageDigest instance;

    public MessageDigest() {}

    private MessageDigest(java.security.MessageDigest instance)
    {
        this.instance = instance;
    }

    public static MessageDigest getInstance(String algorithm) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException
    {
        if (algorithm == null) return null;

        try
        {
            if (algorithm.equals("SHA-1"))
                return (MessageDigest) Class.forName("android.security.Sha1MessageDigest").newInstance();
            else if (algorithm.equals("MD5"))
                return (MessageDigest) Class.forName("android.security.Md5MessageDigest").newInstance();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {}

        return new MessageDigest(java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance(algorithm));
    }

    public void update(byte[] input)
    {
        instance.update(input);
    }

    public byte[] digest()
    {
        return instance.digest();
    }

    public byte[] digest(byte[] input)
    {
        return instance.digest(input);
    }
}
```